# Find socket with parameter

Tags: node.js

I have a question: How to find a socket with parameter.

For example, when client connects I add to socket some parameters:

```
socket.name = 'John';
socket.country = 'USA';
socket.age = 25;
```

And how to search sockets which have a country `China` for example.

```
socket.on('search', function(country) {
     // Give list of sockets were (socket.country) = country
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a global array of sockets and filter it with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var socketList = [];

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    // add socket to list on connection
    socketList.push(socket);

    // remove socket from list on disconnect
    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
        socketList.splice(socketList.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });

    socket.on('search', function(country) {
         // Give list of sockets where (socket.country) = country
        var filteredList = socketList.filter(function(s) {
            return s.country == country;
        });
    });
});
```

If you have a huge number of sockets and `filter`ing in O(n) time is too slow, you could alter the code to maintain a lookup table for O(1) access, which might look like an object whose members are arrays of sockets:

```
{
    "USA": [socket, socket, socket, ...],
    "Canada": [socket, socket, ...],
    ...
}
```

And you access each list with `socketLookupTable[countryName]`.